# OAuth2: Protecting non-user resources

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0

I have an API. Say it allows users to update their score on a leaderboard. This uses OAuth2.

Clients who use OAuth2 on behalf of a user have 32 character ids and secrets.

I also have some resources that are "public" and not owned by a user. Say getting the overall leaderboard.

I want clients to be able to access them via the API. However, these clients may not be users (other websites say), and implementing an OAuth flow seems overly complicated. However, I'd also like clients to identify themselves to keep track of who's using it and to implement, say, rate checking if needed.

Is there anything in OAuth2 that allows for this? client_credentials is for 'trusted clients' and these won't be as such.

Alternatively, do I use, say, a different form of authentication for these endpoints, so that instead of Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN] the client would do Authorization: Token [CLIENT_ID]?

Answer (score 0):

For the non-protected resources, you can put those on the internet without any OAuth protection.

However, if you do that, you can't really trust the information the client sends you. So it depends on how important it is to validate the client ID they send.

If it's for throttling, that might be enough justification to run that through OAuth so someone doesn't lie about their client ID and steal someone else's bandwith. But that's a judgement call.

If you need to trust the information that they're sending in, even if it's just an identifier, then you're probably better off having them send in their access token, rather than coming up with a special protocol & definition of a different token.

Or just trust the ID they send.

Comment: Hmm. Good point. They could have to exchange their client_id for a token. It sort of looks like Twitter does something similar with application-only authentication: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only